# How to point to wrapping custom element with v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I currently have a custom `vue-form` component:

In my common HTML it kind of looks something like this:

```
<vue-form>
    <input type="text" v-model="test">
    <input type="password" v-model="test2">
</vue-form>
```

Note that this is not a Vue template.

My v-model keeps pointing to my root component when in this case I would like my v-model to point the the actual component that is wrapping my content.

For the `vue-form` component I am simply using a slot like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to get the `v-model` binding to point towards the wrapping component instead of the root element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Scoped Slots [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

Edit:
Here is working example:

```
<div id="app">
<vue-form v-bind:model="x">
<template scope="props">
  <input type="text" v-model="props.model.test">
  <input type="password" v-model="props.model.test2">
</template>
</vue-form>
</div>

new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: function() {
return {
  x: {
      test: 'John',
      test2: 'Smith'
  }
}
},
components: {
'vue-form': {
    template: `<div><slot :model="model"></slot></div>`,
  props: ['model']
}
}});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40vu9tx8/)

Just notice that this solution requires from you to propagate property from component to slot by :model="model" part in slot declaration.